# how to set color of frame of Qframe?

Tags: python, pyside2, qframe

I want to set a color of the frame provide by QFrame in pyside2.

Below document provide complete details, how to create a frame with the different style, like a box, panel, Hline, etc...

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QFrame.html#detailed-description

My question is how I can set the color of that frame. 
I tried to set the color using "background-color" and "border" stylesheet, but not get output which I want.

Below is my code.

```
class HLine(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, color="black"):
        super(HLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
        self.setLineWidth(0)
        self.setMidLineWidth(3)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid %s" % color)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % color)
        pass
```

Out without any stylesheet.

[image]

Output with border style sheet

[image]

Out with background-color stylesheet

[image]

both are stylesheet giving unwanted output.

How can I set color without changing the look of the frame?

Comment: I have a big question, what output do you want?

Comment: First output with blue color, wihtout "thickness"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Qt Style Sheet you can use `QPalette`:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPalette
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class HLine(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, color=QColor("black")):
        super(HLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
        self.setLineWidth(0)
        self.setMidLineWidth(3)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setColor(color)

    def setColor(self, color):
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, color)
        self.setPalette(pal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    lay = QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(HLine())

    for color in [QColor("red"), QColor(0, 255, 0), QColor(Qt.blue)]:
        h = HLine()
        h.setColor(color)
        lay.addWidget(h)

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]